# How to create certificate chain (.pem) from the leaf using command line?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool, pem

On Windows, the certificate viewer gives a decent UI for viewing an entire certificate path and exporting the base64 .cer files for each leaf, intermediate, and root. These exported files I've been cat'ing together to create a .pem chain that I need for my specific platform.

I've recently made a switch to Mac OS. I only have the leaf .cer file that I need to turn into a pem chain. Is there a way I could achieve this through the command line? Or another Mac tool?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

An overview of how the certificate viewer works on Windows - When you have a leaf certificate, and double click to open it, you might see the entire chain if the CA chain is already trusted by the OS, or just the leaf certificate if the CA Chain is not trusted.

Windows looks at the `Issuer Distinguished Name`, and sees if the CA that issued that certificate is trusted. If it is trusted, it starts to form the certificate chain. It does the chain construction until the `Issuer DN` and the `Subject DN` are the same.

So when you have just the leaf certificate, you see the entire chain, but you technically don't have the whole chain in the certificate file. So what you were doing by downloading the each CA certificate and putting together would be the only option.